# Distance calculation using GPS Co ordinates gives wrong value in c

Tags: c, gps, distance

I am using PIC24f and GPS module L80 for my application. From gps module successfully i can able to get the latitude and longitude.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
float Distance=0;
void distancebygps(float lat1, float lon1, float lat2, float lon2)
{
    double dlon=0,dlat=0,a=0,c=0,dist=0;
    dlon = (lon2 - lon1) * (M_PI / 180.0);
    dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * (M_PI / 180.0);
    a = pow(sin(dlat/2.0), 2) + cos(lat1*(M_PI / 180.0)) * cos(lat2*(M_PI /180.0)) * pow(sin(dlon/2.0), 2);
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    dist = 6367 * c;
    Distance = (float) (Distance + dist);  
    printf("%.2f",Distance);
}
void Getgpsvalue()
{
    // code to get latitude and longitude
    //  getting  latitude and longitude 
    distancebygps(Latitude1,Longitude1,Latitude2,Longitude2);
}
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        Getgpsvalue();
        Delayms(10000);
    }
}
```

This is my code for calculating the distance from latitude and longitude. When I am passing a value, for instance `(12.9229, 80.1275, 13.0102, 80.2157)` it gives the correct distance as `13.614012 Km`.

When I run in infinite loop it gets the value from L80 gps module it add up the distance correctly for some Km after that  it is giving the value as `12454.12` or `168.12` or `4578.35` like these values.

Why is it getting some unknown value? What may be the problem?

Sometimes the same code is working correctly and sometimes wrongly. Is there any wrong in calculating the distance formula?

Comment: Why are you mixing `float`s and `double`s, can you use only `double`s?

Comment: Mixing float and double will create  a problem? @– Alter Mann

Comment: Of course, you may experience some loss of precision here: `Distance = (float) (Distance + dist);`

Comment: @ MCVE. – Eugene Anisiutkin i just posted problematic function alone ...  seperate functions are written  for getting gps value and delay . During conversion it gives me wrong value mainly when adding previous distance and obtained distance..

Comment: how could i overcome this issue .. if i had  type casted  double  to float ...@Alter Mann

Comment: Try replacing all `float`s to `double` in the code.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I have changed and i had declared latitude and longitude as float ... will it create a problem?

Comment: You update your GPS data every 10 seconds, so the new and old values are very close to each other, right? Could you please post some example readings from the GPS?

Comment: @arun, You really should use `double` for these calculations. Everywhere. change everything to `double`, test it, if the problem remains, then it's not in the distance calculation.

Comment: (12.955124,80.242935,12.956830,80.243797)---0 sec
(12.954449,80.241058,12.955124,80.242935)---10 sec
(12.955013,80.237869,12.954449,80.241058)---20 sec
(12.955348,80.236282,12.955013,80.237869)---30 sec

Comment: @arun don't post information we've extracted from you in comments, but update your question.

Comment: Again the problem exists.....after changing float to double

Comment: @ Eugene Will check with debugger

Comment: after checking with debugger return from the function gives correctly value but at the time of adding gives unknown value..@ – Eugene Anisiutkin

Comment: I suspect that you have not defined a prototype for your function. Then you go on to pass doubles to a function that wants floats or you pass floats but the compiler has silently assumed that all your arguments should be ints. Could you please switch on warnings and compile again?

Comment: @M Oehm and @ Eugene cleared all the warning and checked .Program has zero errors and warnings

Comment: Sometimes dlon or dlat gives -ve value this  would be a problem?@  Eugene Anisiutkin

Comment: when dlon or dlat is negative distance value gets changed... from 0.12 to 17205.12 i noticed with debugger...

Comment: Oh, I see! You use the `pow` function to calculate the square of a number. Use `x*x` instead of `pow(x, 2)`. The problem is with a negative `x`, which some implementations of `pow` can't deal with. (Some compilers recognise powers of integers and treat them specially. Some don't. Basically, `pow(a, b)` is `exp(log(a) * b)` and taking the logarithm of a negative number is illegal.) That should give you NaNs though, not any random numbers.

Comment: Programming getting restarted because of (x*x) instead of pow function

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the studio! i see no point in further discussions without it. Deleting usless comments

Comment: i have checked twice formula's  also correct ,at the time of adding only i am getting unknown value.....

Comment: @arun The only idea i have left is that there is a typo somewhere there

Comment: @Eugene Anisiutkin On my analysis distance calculation formula is not a problem ... Some times it add up the distance correctly at some peak it add high value to the distance variable. dist = 6367 * c this calculation also gives correctly it gives values in terms of meters or KM (may be). At the time of adding only a problem. Anyone tel me what is the problem?

Comment: I think i finally tracked down the problem. How unlikely it will sound, but the problem comes down to this: The calculations are correct, but the recived answer is just too small for double to hold. In some extrieme cases that can happen  if the two coords are just too close to each other

Comment: some  test data at which it fails please. I'll test just for the sake of finding an answer. I just ran some basic test under QT creator.... well... everything works fine. I am at a loss.

Comment: so i should not add up the resulting value  to distance if below some threshold value right ?

Comment: It is not clear (for me ) that all code  like "// code to get latitude and longitude" are included in the same c-file , if not would it not be worth trying to declare distance as static ?

Comment: @arun Probably yes, basically if two coords are just too close together, say 0.01 meter(you know that they are 100% this close), you should probably avoid using this formula.